# conditionally trust html from angular scope variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an html snippet as follows:

```
<span id="notification"> {{ message }} </span>
```

In order to bind to html, I need to do the following:

```
<span id="notification" ng-bind-html="message"></span>
```

Ideally, I want to be able to set a flag to trust $scope.message as html... So my options are to use an ng-if with duplicate code, but this is not ideal because I would like this to the same id for both message elements. I was also looking into taking advantage of ng-attr, but don't believe this will work.

Is there a way I can conditionally add "ng-bind-html" and "ng-bind", so evaluate a flag and remove the undesired attribute? I am new to angularjs.

Comment: if `message` doesn't contain any HTML, it will still display properly using `ng-bind-html`;  there shouldn't be a reason to conditionally switch back and forth, unless you are concerned that there is HTML in the `message` that you don't want to trust, but that would be an entirely separate issue.

Comment: My main concern is that there could be a chance somewhere in the app where we directly display content provided by the user (yes a bigger problem, but I don't want to make it worse). If the user names something "<script>doBadStuff()</script>" I don't want this being rendered.

Comment: then yes, I think the answer @epelc provided is the way to go.  you could even override the default whitelist for `$sanitize` and then not even have to set a flag on specific content.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the [$sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) service and a function to either return just your message or return your message wrapped in `$sanitize`. Then you could just use `ng-bind`

An example

`<span id="notification" ng-bind="notificationCtrl.getMessage(message, true)"></span>`

In your controller

```
this.getMessage = function(msg, sanitize) {
   if (sanitize) return $sanitize(msg)
   return msg
}
```